# Access OneDrive file with .svc extension using Microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files, microsoft-graph-sites

We have to access several OneDrive files using Microsoft graph API. This works well until we met some file whose name ends with `.svc` (they are regular files).

We have a request that looks like:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/account@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/drive/root:/file.svc`

And it fails with a `400 Bad request` (all other requests succeed).

We have tried the following, without success:

- Escape the dot `.` with `%2E`
- I’ve seen that the `.svc` extension was stripped, so doubled it, the file name becomes `file.svc.svc`

How to encode a file name with a `.svc` extension so graph API accepts it? (There is a way for sure, since we managed to upload such a file)

Comment: You can't add the .svc extension to SharePoint/onedrive, as it's recognized as WCF (Windows Communication Framework) service file. It's [documented here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3#ID0EAABAAA=2016).

Comment: @Dev dude… https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3#ID0EAABAAA=Modern And as I said, the `.svc` files are present, uploaded on OneDrive, so that’s possible 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access file content itself, the URI had to be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/account@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/drive/root:/file.svc:/content` (the `:/content` at the end does the trick, because it is semantically correct).